# IAP with a plist file, consumable is acting as nonconsumable for BOOL values

Tags: ios, plist, in-app-purchase

I am following a Ray Wenderlich tutorial, and even when I use his code, same thing happens.

I am hosting all the files on my own server, which is connecting, downloading and verifying the receipt perfectly. My problem is, when I have in the plist the consumable variable set to false, it acts as its true, and vice versa.

I am just so confused as why it is doing the opposite of what it should.

so with this code, it thinks it is consumable.

```
<dict>
    <key>productIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.test.hello</string>
    <key>icon</key>
    <string>icon_hardwords.png</string>
    <key>consumable</key>
    <false/>
    <key>bundleDir</key>
    <string>HardWords</string>
</dict>
```

This is the code for providing the download for the transaction.

```
- (void)provideContentForTransaction:
(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
               productIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

IAPProduct * product = _products[productIdentifier];

if (transaction.downloads) {

    product.skDownload = transaction.downloads[0];
    if (transaction.downloads.count > 1) {
        NSLog(@"Unexpected number of downloads!");
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
     startDownloads:transaction.downloads];

} else {

    // Put the code from before here
    IAPProduct * product = _products[productIdentifier];

    if (product.info.consumable) {
        [self
         purchaseConsumable:product.info.consumableIdentifier
         forProductIdentifier:productIdentifier
         amount:product.info.consumableAmount];
    } else {
        NSURL * bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle].resourceURL
                             URLByAppendingPathComponent:product.info.bundleDir];
        [self purchaseNonconsumableAtURL:bundleURL
                    forProductIdentifier:productIdentifier];
    }

    [self notifyStatusForProductIdentifier:productIdentifier
                                    string:@"Purchase complete!"];

    product.purchaseInProgress = NO;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:
     transaction];

}

}
```

This is the NSAssert that it stops at in the code

```
- (void)buyProduct:(IAPProduct *)product
{
NSAssert(product.allowedToPurchase, @"This product isn't allowed to be purchased");

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
product.purchaseInProgress = YES;
SKPayment *paypment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product.skProduct];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:paypment];

}
```